# "Email" as a mass noun / mailbox

Tags: contemporary-latin, technology

I understand (perhaps wrongly) **litterae electronicae** to be a particular piece of email and **cursus electronicus** to be the *way* that email moves around or perhaps the system of networked computers that transmits email. But what is an appropriate word for the thing you check when you "check your email"?

In English, we express this by using "email" as a mass noun (i.e. by omitting the article), but I don't think that carries over to Latin. Perhaps a word for "mailbox" would make the most sense, but the best I've found in *Smith's Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary* is *tabellarius publicus,* and I'm not sure that makes sense here.

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish the expression "*casilla electrónica*" is used to refer to the "e-mailbox". Hence, I would propose something like

> arca electronica

where *arca* (nominative singular, feminine), according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arca#Latin), is used to refer to a box to store safe things, and *electronica* is the nom. s. f. of *[electronicus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electronicus#Latin)*.

Another option could be to use *[capsa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capsa#Latin)* instead of *arca*.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say *cursus electronicus*.
While it also stands for the system, it is not unusual to use metonymy like this.
Compare to English, where we use the word "email" liberally for all aspects of email.